# Laravel forgot Password 1/1) Swift_TransportException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new to Laravel and looking to enhance my skills in using Laravel framework 5.4. But I don't know what to do when I encounter this error:

1/1) Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required

Is it something problem in my env file? or config file?
Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Please display your .env file mail configuration and config/mail.php mail configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check your .env and config/mail.php mail configuration like :

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="mypass"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

config/mail.php

```
'from' => ['address' => 'myusername@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Test'],
```

If you can change in `.env` or `config/mail.php` then clear the cache like:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Hope this help for you !!!

Comment: do you mean I will put my main email account there on the env? like deverajaycee07@yahoo.com? like that?

Comment: @JayzdeVera Yes

Comment: Solutuion Pvt Ltd 1 including the mail port? Sorry new to laravel 5.4

Comment: @JayzdeVera which server are you use?

Comment: lamp phpmyadmin? I'm using ubuntu 16.04 os

Comment: @JayzdeVera which mail server are you use?

Comment: @JayzdeVera You should follow this link(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_sending_email.htm)

Comment: It worked! Thankyou so much! Sorry I got a bit confused in the mail server.

Answer (score 2):

This means you have entered invalid information in your `.env` file for your SMTP server configuration.

Check the authentication configuration with your email provider, as well as the `mail.php` configuration file to get more information.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to find out.